# Asp.net user authentication and authorization

Tags: asp.net

Iam new to asp.net and working on a web project. There are different users and each user has specific role.Like admin, visitor, registered user etc. The question is what method to use to implement security. Is there any standard way to implement both authentication and authorization. I am using SQL Server 2008. Please tell a standard method.

Thanks

Comment: This link will help you probably http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look into the following topics:

Asp.net roleprovider : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx

Asp.net memberschipprovider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Additional information: http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/role-based-authorization-cs

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the basic principles before you proceed.

Start with [ASP.NET Web Application Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/330a99hc.aspx)

[How ASP.NET Security Works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks310b8y.aspx)

[Guide to Claims–based Identity and Access Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx)

Comment: What is an ASP.NET web application exactly? Is that any application with open endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database, which is most definately the best way to go about it, this will be supported if you are running SQL server. This should help you build the database, and give you some insight into how to implement users and permissions.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v510/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc/wpf/setup_sql.html

Good luck!